# Complete address not able to find using geolocation

Tags: javascript, jsp, geolocation

I have piece of code in which I am calculating the distance from the current location and it is working fine when I enter the address till area but when I give complete address (with house no) then it is not able to find the address. however when I pass only area and city then it works fine but I can't stop end user to give only area and city. How to handle this situation.

Is it possible if code can ignore house no and search by using only area or city?

```
<html>
      <%@include file="configuration_parameter.jsp" %>
    <%
try
{
//    HttpSession session_1 = request.getSession(false);       
  // String address = request.getParameter("full_address");
   String address="132/4a,Makdikhera,KALYANPUR , KANPUR, UTTAR PRADESH";
    String rs_creation_date=request.getParameter("rs_creation_date");

//String address="asdfasdfasfasdfasdf";
    %>
    <body onLoad="getLocation()">

<p id="demo"><font face=calibri color=blue>Please wait.. Distance is being calculated from your current location..</font></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<%=Google_API_Map_key%>&sensor=false"></script>
<script>

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";        
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {


var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "<%=address%>";

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

  if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
var xx = document.getElementById("demo");
xx.innerHTML = '<font face=calibri color=grey size=3>Posted by <%=rs_creation_date%> | </font><font face=calibri color=red size=3>Destination distance: Sorry, Unable to find out the destination distance.</font>';
        }
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    var R = 6371;
    var dLat = (latitude-position.coords.latitude) * (Math.PI/180);
    var dLon = (longitude-position.coords.longitude) * (Math.PI/180);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos((position.coords.latitude) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.cos((latitude) * (Math.PI/180)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c; 

function displayLocation(latitude,longitude,distance,adr){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var method = 'GET';
//      var sourcelocation = "london";
        var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+latitude+','+longitude;
        var async = true;

        request.open(method, url, async);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var address = data.results[0];
            var xx = document.getElementById("demo");
            var time = distance/50;
            xx.innerHTML = '<font face=calibri color=grey size=3>Posted by <%=rs_creation_date%> | </font> <font face=calibri color=green size=3>'+distance+' Km away from your current location</font>';

          }

        };
            var retresults = "Source Location :"+address.formatted_address+" Destination Address:"+adr+" Distance:"+distance+" km";

        request.send();
      return retresults;

      };

var adr = address;
var home = displayLocation(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude,d.toFixed(2),adr); 
} 

}
        ); 

}
</script>
<%
} catch (Exception e)
{
    out.println("<font face=calibri color=red>Oops. There is some problem to find out the address details</font>");
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your address is a string, so you could pre-process your address to remove the house number.

It is common to come across problems like this when using mapping APIs, such as the Google Maps API. Google doesn't validate addresses, or try to match them to databases of real addresses. At the end of the day, most address search terms return whatever the algorithm things it should be after parsing the characters in the search term. There is lots of potential for something tricky to come up when parsing the characters in an address search term. This is especially true for addresses in some countries that are not as familiar to the API (Google is probably most familiar with the types of addresses found in major cities in North America and Europe, for instance).

When you run in to problems with an address that doesn't give you correct data on Google's API, you can report errors to Google. I hear they fix them pretty quickly. You can try [this website](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?visit_id=1-636216737512545532-3772858462&rd=1) for reporting.

On a side note, you may want to try an address validation API, like [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com). You can try your address on their [demo website](https://smartystreets.com/demo). They will probably have better results for tricky addresses, especially if you are searching for mailing or shipping addresses. They specialize in matching address search terms to addresses in databases, such as postal data.

Fair disclosure: I worked for SmartyStreets.